# Disable repeat keys only for function keys e.g. (fn + f10)

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-event

Sometimes function keys e.g. <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> gets stuck.

How do I disable repeat keys only for these type of keys e.g. <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>*any function key*</kbd>)

Comment: As a workaround, maybe you could swap the function keys with their secondary function in the BIOS?